# RPM rising to 3000 in neutral and Parking gear this happen after travelling 10 to 20 kms

Tags: hyundai, accent, fast-idle

I have Hundai Accent 2011 model with Automatic transmission,after traveling 10-20 kms when I change gear to neutral or park, the RPM rises to 3000 and doesn't come down. I took the car to the Hyundai service centre, they cleaned the carburetor with Delco spray and it was OK for few minutes, but after traveling 5 kms the RPM came back up to 3000 in neutral and park.

please suggest  what could be the problem?

Comment: Its either a vacuum leak or a fast idle valve.  Vacuum leak could be a bad vacuum line, bad vacuum device, injector not seated properly, cracked intake manifold, bad intake manifold gasket, or bad throttle body gasket.